# want to upload and retrieve image and any other format file in to my sql server database in byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

For saving File Info:

```
string[] fileStream = File.ReadAllBytes(files[1]);
FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(files[1]);
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[1]);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[1]);
```

Inserting an object[,] in to database:

```
rowData[0, 0] = "@cvTitle";
rowData[0, 1] = fileName;
rowData[1, 0] = "@cvData";
rowData[1, 1] = fileStream;
rowData[2, 0] = "@recieveDate";
rowData[2, 1] = DateTime.Now;
rowData[3, 0] = "@cvSize";
rowData[3, 1] = fileinfo.Length;
rowData[4, 0] = "@fileTypeID";
rowData[4, 1] = extension.ToString();
```

But its not upload it in correct format.

And how can I get the same file from my database without any change in my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have string array instead of byte array

your updated code for uploading image

```
byte[] fileStream = File.ReadAllBytes(files[1]);
FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(files[1]);
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[1]);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[1]);
```

for retrieving the image

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your query", Your Connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.text;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code wouldn't work is because you are using a string[] rather than a byte[], which is the return type of the ReadAllBytes command.

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(files[1]); // assuming files[1] is a string pointing to the file with a relative/absolute path
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(files[1]);
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[1]);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[1]);
```

And for your other problem:

```
byte[] fileBytes = rowData[1, 1];
```